# Angular2+ Radio Button Not Clickable

Tags: angular, forms, radio-button

I have a dropdown that once selected presents to the user a list of questions. Each question has the same set of answers (`Yes`, `No`, `Unknown`) which I would like to be represented by `radio` buttons. After some research I came up with the following code:

```
<fieldset *ngIf="selectedService">
    <div class="row form-group" *ngFor="let question of selectedService.questions; let i = index">
        <!-- START Service Specific Questions START -->
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <label>{{ question.questionText }}</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4" *ngFor="let answer of question.answers; let n = index">
            <input *ngIf="n != 2" type="radio" class="k-radio" name="{{ question.typeValue + i }}" [value]="answer.answerValue" (click)="getValue(answer.answerValue)" />
            <input *ngIf="n == 2" type="radio" class="k-radio" name="{{ question.typeValue + i }}" [value]="answer.answerValue" (click)="getValue(answer.answerValue)" checked/>
            <label class="k-radio-label">{{ answer.answerText }}</label>
        </div>
        <!-- END Service Specific Questions END -->
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

The `*ngIf` conditions on the `inputs` are so `Unknown` is always chosen on init.

The list of questions/answers renders fine but I cannot actually click on any of the options for answers. Any suggestions where I am going wrong?

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce. When I use this code in a Stackblitz I can select an answer without a problem https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rgneza?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Are you clicking on the label or radio(circle) itself?

Comment: rejnev either or. @user184994 maybe it's because I am within a reactive form? Do I need to change anything in that case?

Comment: Are you able to create a Stackblitz that reproduces the error please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the classes `k-radio` and `k-radio-label` (using Kendo UI for Angular) needed `id=""` and `for=""` in the respective elements to work properly:

```
<fieldset *ngIf="selectedService">
    <div class="row form-group" *ngFor="let question of selectedService.questions; let i = index">
        <!-- START Service Specific Questions START -->
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <label>{{ question.questionText }}</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4" *ngFor="let answer of question.answers; let n = index">
            <input id="{{ question.typeValue + n }}" *ngIf="n != 2" type="radio" class="k-radio" name="{{ question.typeValue + i }}" [value]="answer.answerValue" (click)="getValue(answer.answerValue)" />
            <input id="{{ question.typeValue + n }}" *ngIf="n == 2" type="radio" class="k-radio" name="{{ question.typeValue + i }}" [value]="answer.answerValue" (click)="getValue(answer.answerValue)" checked/>
            <label class="k-radio-label" for="{{ question.typeValue + n }}">{{ answer.answerText }}</label>
        </div>
        <!-- END Service Specific Questions END -->
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: great answer!  @Milo